# golang - юзать константы по всему проекту

Tags: импорт

хотелось бы понять, как в GO правильно структурировать проект (сайт)

хочу первым делом инициализировать все константы/переменные/структуры
для этого создал /vars/c.go, из которой подгружаю все константы
вот только он ругается, если из другого файла вызвать константу, хочет чтобы этот "vars" был имортирован непосредственно в файл
если есть /vars/vars.go и /vars2/vars2.go, и в обоих "package vars", то из vars2.go я НЕ могу вызвать константу из vars.go

мне что в каждый файл надо будет импортировать всё?
а потом, если поменялось что-то, везде переписывать??
А как сделать что-то вроде заголовочных .h-файлов в C/C++ ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: okokokokokokokok